# ASCII to Binary to Unary Solution Prints Blank Line

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, ascii

Basically, for this practice problem I must turn ASCII character string input into binary and then turn that into unary, a series of 0s and spaces.

For example: 'C' = '1000011' = '0 0 00 0000 0 00'.

Unfortunately, the code only prints a blank line when printing variable 'answer', which is supposed to be the 0s and spaces string. I cannot find anything wrong it, but two compilers return the same blank line.

```
import sys
import math
import binascii

# Auto-generated code below aims at helping you parse
# the standard input according to the problem statement.

message = "C"#input()

# Function which transforms text into a byte
def text_to_bits(text, encoding='utf-8', errors='surrogatepass'):
    bits = bin(int(binascii.hexlify(text.encode(encoding, errors)), 16))[2:]
    return bits.zfill(8 * ((len(bits) + 7) // 8))

# Sets up a switch to determine which block and of what type it is in
switch = 2
answer = ""

# Transforms string message into string of bits
byte = text_to_bits(message)
byte = byte[1:8]

for bit in byte:
    if bit == 1 and switch == 2:
        switch = 1
        answer = answer + "0 0"            
    elif bit == 1 and switch == 1:
        answer = answer + "0"            
    elif bit == 1 and switch == 0:
        switch = 1
        answer = answer + " 0 0"
    elif bit == 0 and switch == 2:
        switch = 0
        answer = answer + "00 0"
    elif bit == 0 and switch == 1:
        switch = 0
        answer = answer + " 00 0"        
    elif bit == 0 and switch == 0:
        answer = answer + "0"                

# Write an action using print
# To debug: print("Debug messages...", file=sys.stderr)

print(answer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `bit` is always `'0'` or `'1'`. It is never equal to `0` or `1`, so none of the conditions in the cascaded `if` is ever true. Change `0` and `1` to the corresponding characters strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison operator is not correct, you would need to do:

```
if bit == "1" and switch == 2:
...
```